# How can I add a block element to the product view in magento without editing an existing template?

Tags: magento, templates, module, block, output

I'd like to add a static box under the price on each product page, but I dont want to overwrite an existing template file (e.g. catalog/product/view.phtml) to render it's child block.

I tried to add a block element via frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>

        <reference name="product.info">
           <block type="telllowerpricelink/linkbox" name="telllowerpricelink.linkbox" template="telllowerpricelink/link.phtml" before="product.description" output="toHtml" />
        </reference>

    </default>
</layout>
```

Then i built a rudimental module:
app/code/local/MyPackage/TellLowerPriceLink/Block/LinkBox.php

```
<?php
class MyPackage_TellLowerPriceLink_Block_Link extends Mage_Core_Block_Template 
{

}
?>
```

app/code/local/MyPackage/TellLowerPriceLink/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyPackage_TellLowerPriceLink>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyPackage_TellLowerPriceLink>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mypackage_telllowerpricelink>
                <class>MyPackage_TellLowerPriceLink_Block</class>
            </mypackage_telllowerpricelink>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And my templatefile:
design/frontend/base/default/template/telllowerpricelink/link.phtml

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world!';
?>
```

So my questions are:
1. The main question: Is it possible to add the html-output (btw: I dont see it) at the end of the parent block element without editing its template (a la renderChildHtml)?
2. Is it possible to store my template file in this folder or have I to copy the hole default theme folder into a own theme?

Thanks a lot, I have googled and read a lot but didnt find a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That's only possible with blocks derived from Mage_Core_Block_Text_List block so in your case it isn't possible but you could add your block to reference content (a container that renders all the children from layout files) and wrap your block into a div with style="display: none;" set and then move it with a javascript to the expected location.
2. It's possible but instead you could change the default theme in admin under system->configuration->general->design->package
   The name that you will use here will be the name of your theme folder (note that this changes the theme for your entire store) so you can create your folder in desing/your_theme_name_from_admin/{layout, template} and put only files that you require to override in there. With this you could copy only the phtml file that you would like to override and change it on the new location while keeping the default copy in tact.

Comment: Thank you so much. I expected something like that. The workaround for the first question is nothing I wont to use. I dislike JavaScript-only workarounds. But thanks for that. The solution for the second question is acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: If this answers your question you should accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I was on the way. It was my first comment and I added it accidentally.